# How to make a change to a global dictionary while looping on lists of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, global

Inside the `update_data()` function, I declare the dictionaries global, but once I loop and assign them to a local variable I can no longer change the global `dict`.

The terrible hack I made shows how it should work. But if I have to add MANY new dictionary pairs to the list, it becomes unworkable since I also have to add to the `if..elif` statements. It gets very ugly very fast.

Is there a 'proper', 'elegant', or 'pythonic' way of making the assignment to the global dictionary?
I am using `python 2.7`, obviously, but if there is a different solution for `python 3.x` feel free to comment as it will be migrated soon.

```
# global dicts
temps = {0: 25, 1: 28, 2: 29, 3: 28}  # ...
temps_old = {}
flows = {0: 1.23, 1: 2.45}  # ...
flows_old = {}
# ...


def update_data():
    global temps, temps_old, flows, flows_old
    # loop and create list of changes
    for my_list, my_list_old, code in [(temps, temps_old, 't'), (flows, flows_old, 'f')]:
        xmlsnip = ''
        for key, value in my_list.iteritems():
            include = True
            if key in my_list_old:
                if my_list_old[key] == value:
                    include = False  # block it the data has not changed
            if include:
                my_list[key] = False
                tag = "{0}{1:02d}".format(code,int(key))
                xmlsnip += '<{0}>{1}</{2}>'.format(tag, value, tag)
        if xmlsnip != '':
            #  What I'd lik eto do is assign to the global list:
            my_list_old = my_list.copy()
            # but it only assigns to the local variable, not the global one I 'pointed' to
            if code == 't':
                temps_old = my_list.copy()
            elif code == 'f':
                flows_old = my_list.copy()
            print '     ' + xmlsnip
        else:
            print '     no changes for ' + code

print '## test update_data finds all differences ##'
update_data()
print '## change 2 temps and 1 flow ##'
temps[2] = 30
temps[1] = 29
flows[0] = 1.25
print '## test that update only finds the 3 changes ##'
update_data()
print '## make no changes and verify it finds nothing ##'
update_data()
```

The output looks like this:

```
## test update_data finds all differences ##
     <t00>25</t00><t01>28</t01><t02>29</t02><t03>28</t03>
     <f00>1.23</f00><f01>2.45</f01>
## change 2 temps and 1 flow ##
## test that update only finds the 3 changes ##
     <t01>29</t01><t02>30</t02>
     <f00>1.25</f00>
## make no changes and verify it finds nothing ##
     no changes for t
     no changes for f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you need to reset the elements of the global dictionary without creating a new object.

Try this update:

```
    if xmlsnip != '':
        #  What I'd lik eto do is assign to the global list:
        my_list_old.clear()  # remove existing entries
        my_list_old.update(my_list)  # add new entries, keep object pointer
        # but it only assigns to the local variable, not the global one I 'pointed' to
```